# how can visualizing binary file like image with matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing

i need to visualize a binary file (for example .exe) like an image
this code to pack the bytes into an image in c# language :

```
var width = (int)Math.Sqrt(fi.Length * 8);
width = width + 8 - (width % 8);
var length = (int)(fi.Length * 8 / width);

Func<byte, int, Color> getcolor =
        (b, m) => (b & m) == m ? Color.Black : Color.White;

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, length + 1))
{
    var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(exefile);

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    foreach (var @byte in buffer)
    {
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 0, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x80));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 1, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x40));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 2, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x20));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 3, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x10));

        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 4, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x8));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 5, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x4));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 6, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x2));
        bitmap.SetPixel(x + 7, y, getcolor(@byte, 0x1));

        x += 8;
        if (x >= width)
        {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
    }

    bitmap.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(exefile, ".tif"), ImageFormat.Tiff);
}
```

this code convert binary file to image like this :
[image]

can anybody give me the Matlab implementation of this code ?

Comment: Can you upload the binary file?

Comment: @JeruLuke https://www.file-upload.com/eztinwfv1700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How can I convert a binary file to another binary representation, like an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408864/how-can-i-convert-a-binary-file-to-another-binary-representation-like-an-image)

%Matlab has the function bitget that does what you want. You then need to put all the bits in a square matrix.

```
[f,d]=uigetfile('*.*');
fid=fopen([d,filesep,f],'r');
d = fread(fid,inf,'*uint8'); %load all data as bytes.
fclose(fid);
width = sqrt(length(d)*8);
width = width+8-mod(width,8); %make sure width is a multiple of 8
IM = false(width); %binary matrix
x=1;y=1;
for ct = 1:length(d)
    v=bitget(d(ct),[1:8]);
    IM(x:x+7,y)=v;
    x=x+8;
    if x>width
        x=1;y=y+1;
    end
end
imagesc(IM) %display image
```

Comment: it's work but why the generated image is different in c# and matlab?

Comment: can it be that it is rotated by 90 degrees?
try this:

    imagesc(IM')

Comment: how can change background and pixel color ? image background likely black and pixels is white.

Comment: two options. Change the colormap, or change the bit valueu.
easiest is imagesc(~IM) (the tilde is a not-operator, so it flips the bits)